# Using a Backbone listener with a Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, backbone.js, frontend, backbone-events

Not particularly an expert with front end so seeking some help, apologies if this has been answered.

I have a backbone listener that is set to run some function when the "data" event occurs:

```
myResults.on("data", function() { ... });
```

is it possible to somehow get and output of the data from within the function to go into a Vue component so it can later be rendered by Vue? 
Or is there a way to make a Vue listener that can listen to the Backbone listener?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not very familiar with vue syntax, but you could try passing an object reference view props, something like:

```
const data = {
  title: ''
}

<blog-post title={data.title}></blog-post>

myResults.on("data", function() { data.title = "Something new" });
```